# What is the problem with this surface shading?

Tags: modeling

I am recreating this broken mesh on the right with another built with primitives, but the lighting looks off:

[image]

There appears to be a "white spot" where the shading isn't working properly. All normals are facing the correct way and the mesh is set to use Smooth shading and Auto Smooth is enabled.

From another angle:

[image]

Flat shading:

[image]

Normals:

[image]

What is going on here?

EDIT:

After I joined the new mesh to the existing base mesh (CTRL + J), the auto smooth shader picked up a new shading angle form the base object and it returned to normal:

[image]

Comment: What is the angle set to on auto-smooth?  Can you export that object into another blend file and attach it to the post?

Comment: So when I joined the new object to the existing orange base mesh, the shading returned to normal. I guess it must have picked up a new shading angle from the object it was joining to? Anyway, seems to be good now. I'll have to keep that auto-shading angle in mind for next time. Thanks!